# Ionic 4 AngularFire performance monitor not working

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4, angularfire2, firebase-performance

I have been for a while trying to understand why AngularFire https://github.com/angular/angularfire perfomance monitor https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/performance/getting-started.md is not working on IOS and Android using IONIC. Is there a need for Cordova plugins? does it not work for devices?

I thought it would work right of the bat using the installation https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/ionic/cli.md but nothing worked. So I installed `cordova-plugin-firebasex` and it's working. But I really want to use `@angular/fire`.

Any advice?
Thank in advance.

Comment: does it work for you for Ionic as web app?

Comment: Tried with `ionic serve` while I was working and that did not work either

Comment: I should then consider perhaps this a bug and go directly into their github repo and add an issue, what do you guys think?

Comment: can you add some details of around what “not working” means: is there an error? etc?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko that is the things, following the angular/fire installations and usage. no errors pop up. nothing, it feels that it is working. But it is not, there is no connection with firebase. I know it is working my configs, because I can use functions, firestore, etc... but not performance monitor.

Comment: I see, sorry it seems this is brand new thing and also I see that Google/Firebase state they give no SLA and no guarantees for it to work since its early Beta. It certainly have a web as supported platform, so there is a way to make it work without Cordova plugins. Can you share how exactly you are importing firebase into your project? (not AngularFire but specifically Firebase)

Comment: `Google/Firebase state they give no SLA` oh dear if that is the case then it's my bad. :/ I can't seem to find that information. I followed exactly the angularfire procedure for ionic CLI: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/ionic/cli.md
After that did not work I used https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex#installation then everything worked flawlessly

Comment: yeah check the red text;) https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-web

Comment: ha! many thanks. then this is my bad :)